# Detecting private APIs in iOS application

Tags: objective-c, ios, app-store, iphone-privateapi

I have used AppScanner [detects private APIs](http://www.macworld.com/article/1154799/app_scanner.html)
But, it is detecting almost all function signatures as private APIs with 50% likelihood .
[image: snapshot of a run]

Are these false warnings ?

I agree _font clashes with internal API but why are remaining public APIs being shown in list ?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the program is dead. Check the site at

http://www.chimpstudios.com/appscanner/index.html

It probably did work well at some point in the past.

Comment: Please use this link to download -
[link] http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/35448/app-scanner
Directly click on "Download Now"

Comment: Hmmm... actually you can use https://github.com/ChimpStudios/App-Scanner... but yeah, you can ignore those 50% warnings for sure.