# How to detect usage of private api before submitting to App Store to avoid rejections

Tags: ios, xcode

App store rejects if the binary contains has some private api usage, I want to detect it upfront.
is there any tool for such

Answer (score 0):

XCode's Validation feature is good or you will get more information about **Detection of private API usage** below

1. [Otool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15074693/4401216)
2. [AppScanner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10899228/4401216)